# how to make full content fit into screen when resizing

Tags: html, css, flexbox, resize

on my website, I want to have 6 'image boxes' (3 in one 'row' and 3 in below 'row'). When I change the size of my screen/tab then these 6 image boxes should be always seen completely. They should always fit into the screen size. My code works somehow but not on the bottom. Only one part of the cards in the second row can be seen after decreasing screen size after a certain amount.

Also, I want my content to take 100% of the screen without a scroll bar popping up.

The web content is divided into 2 parts: The top layout and the imagebox.

this is basically my css-file:

```
* {
font: 18px Verdana;
font-size: 22px; 
}

html{
 height: 100%;
}

body {
font: 18px Verdana;
height: 100%;
margin-left: 30px;
margin-right: 30px;
margin-bottom: 30px;
margin-top: 30px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#topLayout {
height: 190px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}


#imagebox {
height: 80%;
margin-bottom: 0px;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box{   
cursor: pointer;
flex: 0 1 32.5%;
margin-top: 1.2%;
}
```

and this is my html code:

```
<body>

 <div id="topLayout">   

    <div id="block1">
    .....
    </div>

    <div id="block2">
    ....
    </div>

 </div>

 // the images are appended to the imagebox tag in the .js file via a 
  function

<div id="imagebox"></div>

</div>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: We need a _minimal working code snippet_, reproducing the issue. You can get markup/styles by right click on the loaded page and choose "Inspect".

Comment: One problem I see is that the body has a height of 100% plus a margin, which makes the document height always 60px larger than the window height. Solution: use `calc` for the height, or paddings instead of margins and `box-sizing:border-box`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps you. Try this

```
#imagebox {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 top: 230px;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 30px;
 right: 30px;
}
```

Here is a [example](https://codepen.io/baagii95/pen/YEZRXx)